# Detect row enconding Oracle

Tags: encoding, oracle11g, character

thank for your replies now.

My problem is that i've row with utf8 and other in latin1, i like to detect latin1 and covert the values.Anybody know any function to do this?

Comment: What's the type of these rows?

Comment: Any columns have latin1 content but others in utf8, and i would like to detect and convert all in one type

Comment: I mean Oracle column type. Is that varchar or nvarchar?

Comment: column type is varchar

Comment: Then all your data stored in this column has your database character set.There is no utf8 and latin1 - everything is in your DB character set

Comment: the problem is that when i migrate db, i don't convert old latin1 values, and now the new values that i enter are in utf8 but old values continues in latin1 and this generate problems in java,my english is bad sorry

Comment: How did you perform the migration? Check this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch11charsetmig.htm

Comment: I didn't made the migration and o don't know how it was made, but you know any function to detect the encoding of a varchar?

Comment: Why did you write this: " when i migrate db, i don't convert old latin1 values"? I told you that there is no way to detect the encoding - all information is stored in ONE character set = your database character set, which is set when you create the database

Comment: Sorry for all, thanks for your reply, seems that is not possible to fix this problem. Thanks again